# adding trim function to existing sql query

Tags: mysql, joomla

The database tables I'm working with have quotation marks around certain values in 4 specific columns.  I already use the following query to select the data I need, but I'd like to be able to remove the quotes from those columns.

```
SELECT t1.id,
IF(
    LOCATE(' ', t1.name) > 0,
    SUBSTRING(t1.name, 1, LOCATE(' ', t1.name) - 1),
    t1.name
    ) AS memberfirst,
    IF(
    LOCATE(' ', t1.name) > 0,
    SUBSTRING(t1.name, LOCATE(' ', t1.name) + 1),
    NULL
    ) AS memberlast ,
    t1.name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.`profile_key` = 'profile.address1' THEN t2.profile_value END) address,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.`profile_key` = 'profile.city' THEN t2.profile_value END) city,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.`profile_key` = 'profile.postal_code' THEN t2.profile_value END) postal_code,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.`profile_key` = 'profile.phone' THEN t2.profile_value END) phone
FROM users t1
LEFT JOIN user_profiles t2
  ON t1.id = t2.user_id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name
```

The 4 columns I would TRIM the duoble quotes from are: `profile.address1, profile.city, profile.postal_code, and profile.phone` columns. I believe the code would be something like:

`TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM profile.address1) AS trimmed_profile.address1 FROM user_profiles` ... But I'm not exactly sure if it can be integrated above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not `trim()` you need to use `replace()`

```
mysql> select replace('"stackoverflow"','"','') as str;
+---------------+
| str           |
+---------------+
| stackoverflow |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So in your case you can use something as

```
MAX(CASE WHEN replace(t2.profile_key,'"','') = 'profile.address1' THEN t2.profile_value END) address
```

And so on for others.

Comment: This needs to be incorporated into the query.  For whatever reason, when user profile data is added to the site, it is being stored in the database with quotes.  I do not want to modify the data in the database, only modify the data that is output as a result of the query above.

Comment: Yes it does not update the data it will only at the display time `MAX(CASE WHEN replace(t2.profile_key,'"','') = 'profile.address1' THEN t2.profile_value END) address`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! The line ended up having to have the replace part shifted like this: `MAX(CASE WHEN t2.`profile_key` = 'profile.address1' THEN replace(t2.profile_value,'"','') END) address,` but then it worked

Comment: I see ok. Yes mysql has some cool functions which makes life very simple :)